# Looping Through Dictionaries Inside a List

Tags: python, json, pandas, loops

I have a JSON file I'm trying to iterate through. The code to print the part I want is: `print(data['data'][0]['text'])` But I also want to print `print(data['data'][1]['text'])` and `print(data['data'][2]['text'])` and `print(data['data'][3]['text'])` and so forth and so on. I just can't figure out how to loop it since the JSON object is so convoluted.

Comment: Note that you've already decoded the JSON into a Python data structure. JSON isn't relevant to the rest of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the `list` that is `data['data']`.

```py
for item in data['data']:
    print(item['text'])
```